# error C2676 binary '==': 'block' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++, vector, find

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class block {
public:
    int x, y;
    block(int in_x = 0, int in_y = 0) {
        x = in_x;
        y = in_y;
    }
    int get_x() {
        return x;
    }
    int get_y() {
        return y;
    }
    void set_x(int in_x) {
        x = in_x;
    }
    void set_y(int in_y) {
        y = in_y;
    }
};

int main() {
    int x = 5; int y = 5;
    vector<block> blocks = vector <block>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            block p;
            p.set_x(i);
            p.set_y(j);
            blocks.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    //Search block 1,1 in vector
    block b;
    b.set_x(1);
    b.set_y(1);

    vector< block>::iterator item;
    item = find(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), b);
    if (item !=blocks.end())
    {
        cout << endl << "Element found";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Element not found";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am running this code and I am getting this error.

> error C2676   binary '==': 'block' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

The answer might be obvious, but I cannot understand where the problem is, because the error doesn't specify a line. It might be incorrect use of `iterator` and `vector::find()`, but I am not sure.

I tried:

```
    block *b=new block;
    b->set_x(1);
    b->set_y(1);

    vector< block>::iterator item;
    item = find(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), *b);
```

But I am getting the same mistake.

Comment: "he error dont specifie a line" it should. Maybe you are only looking at some "problems" tab of your ide. Find the tab with the compilers output and read the complete message. Error messages do contain line numbers.

Comment: you need `#include <algorithm>` to call `std::find`

Comment: How does `std::find` know what it means to have two blocks equal to each other?

Comment: I use visual studio. I did search the compiler messages and i am getting 8 messages. 7 in other files which i dont understand and one in my file . In line    item = find(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), *b); , i am getting this error:see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,block>(_InIt,const _InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled

Comment: You don't run this code; it fails compilation. The reason for this is that `std::find` compares the object passed as 3rd parameter the elements in the iterator range. You don't implement any logic that allows the compiler to compile `expr1 == expr2` where both expressions are references to `block` objects... The alternative here would be to use `std::find_if`: `item = std::find_if(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), [&b](block& e) { return (b.get_x() == e.get_x()) && (b.get_y() == e.get_y()); });`

Comment: @easyeg's -- See my comment.  The compiler cannot read your intentions -- how does it know when two blocks are equal?   You must write the code to tell the compiler what it means to have two blocks being equal, i.e. implement `operator ==`.

Comment: Btw: Usually for this kind of getter you add the `const` modifier: `int get_x() const { ... }`

Comment: U are right @PaulMcKenzie. An operator solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `block` class lacks an `operator==` to allow 2 `block` objects to be compared for equality. `std::find()` uses that operator when comparing objects in the specified range.

You need to add that operator to your class, eg:

```
class block {
public:
    int x, y;
    ...
    bool operator==(const block &rhs) const {
        return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
    }
};
```

Alternatively:

```
class block {
public:
    int x, y;
    ...
};

bool operator==(const block &lhs, const block &rhs) {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}
```

Comment: U are right.This solved my problem. I understand the use of an operator now